# XSL transformation template returns only the last attribute value

Tags: java, xml, xslt, groovy

Hello and happy new year to the stack overflow community!
This is my first time working with XSL to transform an xml to another xml format. 
Thing is i had this whole thing working(or atleast i thought i did) but the downside is it does not return exactly the same output i expected. 
the desired input and out are as follows : 
Input.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestExecutionSummary>
<ExecutionDate>12-okt-2018 15-43-46</ExecutionDate>
<ExecutedTestCases>3</ExecutedTestCases>
<PassedTestCases>2</PassedTestCases>
<FailedTestCases>1</FailedTestCases>
<TimeTaken>00:03:48</TimeTaken>
<Testcases>
        <TestCaseStatus name="TC001" status="PASS"/>
        <TestCaseStatus name="TC002" status="PASS"/>
        <TestCaseStatus name="TC003" status="FAIL"/>
</Testcases>
</TestExecutionSummary>
```

The output xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<testsuite time="548.000" tests="2" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="1">
<testcase classname="CITS" name="TC001"/>
<testcase classname="CITS" name="TC002"/>
<testcase classname="CITS" name="TC003"/>
<failure type="CITS test failure">unknown failure</failure>
</testsuite>
```

My XSL template is as follows :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <testsuite>
    <xsl:attribute name="time"><xsl:value-of select="TestExecutionSummary/TimeTaken"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="tests"><xsl:value-of select="TestExecutionSummary/ExecutedTestCases"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="errors">0</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="skipped">0</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="failures"><xsl:value-of select="TestExecutionSummary/FailedTestCases"/></xsl:attribute>
                <testcase>
                <xsl:for-each select="TestExecutionSummary/Testcases/TestCaseStatus[@status]">
                    <xsl:attribute name="classname">CITS</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </testcase>
                <failure><xsl:attribute name="type">CITS test failure</xsl:attribute>"unknown error"</failure>           
    </testsuite>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the weird thing i see is this transformation always gives me back this as result and the full list of tests run. The 'xsl:for-each' should loop through the TestCaseStatus node and list the 'name' attributes i thought. But the result is this :

```
    <testsuite time="00:03:48"
           tests="3"
           errors="0"
           skipped="0"
           failures="1">
   <testcase classname="CITS" name="TC003"/>
   <failure type="CITS test failure">"unknown error"</failure>
</testsuite>
```

As you can see i get back the test-name TC003 only and not TC001 and TC002, which i why i was wondering what i did wrong back there. I am trying to look into sample XSL templates and some tutorials in the meantime but i did not encounter any case in any forum where users encountered this issue. So can anyone point me out please what i did wrong there? Thanks in advance!

JFYI if needed i can also post how am am using the XSL to do the transformation in groovy but i think that works fine as i tried this input and the template on an online transformation site and i had the same result.

Comment: You want more than one <testcase> element. Surely the <testcase> markup should be inside the for-each rather than outside?

Comment: It is not clear which result you want as you create a single `testcase` result element but then try to create the same attributes various times, only the last of each name will be output. A single element in XML can not have more than one attribute of the same name i.e. your `testcase` result element can only have one attributed named `name`. I guess you want to map each `TestCaseStatus` element to a `testcase` result element but then you need to move the element into the `for-each`. Or try a good tutorial on XSLT and learn to write templates for the different nodes you want to map.

Comment: @kumesana Got your point, i believe below pointed out the same, quite naive from my part.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yep got your point, i missed it, i should have noticed it, guess i should have spent a bit more time trying to figure this out :)
Thanks a lot pointing that out to me!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the creation of `<testcase>` inside the `xsl:for-each`, rather than outside. Otherwise you are creating just one `<testcase>` element and then trying to add multiple attributes to that. (If you attempt to add an attribute to an element that already has that attribute, the attribute gets replaced).

```
    <xsl:for-each select="TestExecutionSummary/Testcases/TestCaseStatus[@status]">
        <testcase>
            <xsl:attribute name="classname">CITS</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:attribute>
        </testcase>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Or better still, do this

```
    <xsl:for-each select="TestExecutionSummary/Testcases/TestCaseStatus[@status]">
        <testcase classname="CITS" name="{@name}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) to create the `name` attribute.

Comment: thanks!!! Works flawlessly, on the other side i should have considered the basic fact that i was trying to push more than one attribute of the same name on the same element. Upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, you can not have multiple attributes with the same name in a single element.
Maybe you should prepare a comma separated list and put it as the value of the attribute.

Comment: Thanks! Finally it dawned on me :)